# After any bug in Django html i get same exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django

```
Exception inside application: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: ordinal not in range(128)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/http.py", line 213, in __call__
    await self.handle(body)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 150, in __call__
    return await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 333, in wait_for
    return (yield from fut)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 169, in thread_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/http.py", line 246, in handle
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 75, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
  'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Always get the same exception when i get error in html files (include django admin). Project haven't any cyrillic symbols, only latin.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this on an operating system level check the following:

```
$ locale charmap
```

If you get

> locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or
> directory instead of

or similar

> 'ascii'

You need to set UTF-8 in LC_CTYPE and LC_ALL like this:

```
$ export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
$ export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```